# How to get the timestamp of data input in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have form like below:

```
<div id="form">
    <form>
        First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
        Start Time: <input type="hidden" name="starttime" id="starttime">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to store a timestamp in a local storage when data is entered for the first time in **firstname** input. When the form is submitted, I will insert that **timestamp** as Start Time and form submit time as End Time in database.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var startTime = '';
    $('#firstname').change(function (){
      if (startTime) == ''
      {
        var timeStamp = new Date();
        sessionStorage.setItem("startTime",timeStamp);
      }
    });
 });
</script>
```

Now, how do I send the startTime value from javascript to the starttime html input? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I will insert that timestamp as Start Time and form submit time as End Time in database. what does it mean?

Comment: You might start by trying to write some code, see [*MDN: Local Storage*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).

Comment: Let's assume that I entered data in firstname input text box at 2018-10-31 15:25:00 but I submitted the form at 2018-10-31 15:27:00. I want to insert first name and last name along with the Start Time as 2018-10-31 15:25:00 and End Time as 2018-10-31 15:27:00 in database.

Comment: How about using two hidden input fields, which get filled by javascript. The start time changed by an onEdit event, and the endtime changed by onSubmit(). Then you have both values.

Comment: @ivion Won't onEdit event change the start time with every edit in the firstname field? Is it possible to get the timestamp only for first entry in firstname field with onEdit event?

Comment: When the onEdit event is triggered you can check if the Start Time hidden input field already has a value. If so, you simply don't change it. If it's empty then this is the first edit and you populate it with a timestamp.

Comment: Oh, and if any of this data is important or somewhat sensitive then this is not a good way to go about it. An input field can be manipulated by the user and a javascript timestamp will refer to the client's clock (be aware of timezones and other irregularities).

Answer (score 0):

You can use step attribute in your input tag:

`<input type="time" name="timestamp" step="1">`
W3C: `input: type=time`

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what the question is asking, as this is completely irrelevant.